For prime divisors $V,W\subseteq X$ in a smooth threefold $X$ and and integral curve $C\subseteq V\cap W$ with $i(V,W;C)>1$, do we have $V.C=W.C$?
Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety of dimension $3$ over an algebraically closed field. Let $V,W\subseteq X$ be prime divisors, i.e. two integral closed subvarieties of dimension $2$. Let $C\subseteq V\cap W$ be an integral curve, and assume that the intersection multiplicity of $V$ and $W$ at $C$ is greater than $1$, i.e. $i(V,W;C)>1$. Then is it true that $V.C=W.C$?
This feels weird, but here is how I came up with it: denote $m=i(V,W;C)$. Then we have
$$
\begin{align}
(mK_X+mV+W)\cdot_X C &=(mK_X+mV+W)|_V\cdot_V C\\
&=(mK_V+mC+\sum_{C'\neq C}i(V,W;C')C')\cdot_V C\\
&=m\deg K_C+\sum_{C'\neq C}i(V,W;C')C'\cdot_VC
\end{align}
$$
where we used two times adjunction, and where $\cdot_X$ resp. $\cdot_V$ denotes the intersection product on $X$ resp. $V$.
Similarly, we obtain
$$
(mK_X+V+mW)\cdot_X C=m\deg K_C+\sum_{C'\neq C}i(V,W;C')C'\cdot_W C.
$$
Although I'm not 100% sure, I guess that for all distinct integral curves $C,C'\subseteq V\cap W$, we have $C'\cdot_V C=C'\cdot_W C$. After all, intersecting distinct integral curves is only about counting intersection points with the appropriate multiplicities.
Subtracting the two equations, we then obtain $(m-1)(V-W)\cdot_X C=0$, so as $m>1$ we have $V.C=W.C$.
Is this argument correct?

No, this is not true. For instance, take $X = \mathbb{P}^3$, $V$ a quadratic cone, and $W$ a hyperplane that is tangent to $V$ along a ruling $L$ of $V$. Then $V \cap W = 2L$, while $V \cdot L = 2$, but $W \cdot L = 1$.
